# Jquery DataTable Searching behaves incorrectly if string has double quotes " in middle

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I am using jquery.datatable.js and using default smart search of datatable

```
    var dataTable=$('#task_table').DataTable( {
        deferRender:true,
        destroy:true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        select:'multi',
        rowId:'_id',
        scroller:true,
        scrollY:"0px",
        bInfo:false,
        bLengthChange:false,
        columns:self.getColumns(),
        fnDrawCallback:function(){
        }
    } );
    $('#Search').on( 'keyup', function(){
        dataTable.search(this.value).draw();
    });
```

I am using above code to search 
Below are examples of Strings i have in search

Using  dataTable.search(this.value).draw(); this not searching both the string i have mentioned

After using

```
dataTable.search('"'+ this.value +'"').draw();
```

1. `=calc|a!z'ss"s:s`: working fine
2. `!"abc'aa"ads#$%k"as'"`: not Searching after `!"abc'aa"` this part of string

can anyone help to search any string in datatable

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the special characters in your variable prior to searching

```
.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g,'\\$1') + "']"
```

Comment: not working 
tried 
this.value.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g,'\\$1') + "']"

Comment: Weather your entered value has !"abc'aa"ads#$%k"as'" these kind of value, or in the table

Comment: var str = "abc's test#s";

alert(str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, ""));

this return  -- abcs tests

Comment: no i want /([ #;&,.+*~\':"!  this to be searched replace will eliminate "